# phpmyadmin refuse to create table (table already exists ) but I can't see it

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to create a new table in PHPMyAdmin. However it refuses to create the table and says that the (table already exists ) but I can't see it.

I had the same table and db before but I removed the whole xammp but I expected to remove everthing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubTrS.png)

Comment: This is not for S.O., is for dba. In any case, did you try refresh the page with Ctrl + F5? Do you have access to read that database? Please ask this at dba

Comment: Did you try to run the DISCARD command indicated by the error? When you removed XAMPP, did you run the uninstaller or just manually delete some files? It's almost acting like your database wasn't properly deleted, but the DISCARD command should tidy that up.